# Vuejs - Watch nested objects changes not working for dynamic object creation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to watch over a nested object, but it won't detect changes over it's properties, i know this has been asked before, and i tried with some solutions with no luck, so let me first explain in detail what i'm trying to do:

I have a multiselect input where you can choose multiple rooms for a reservation in a hotel:

[image]

So when you select rooms, the form creates new inputs for each room for detailing more information:

[image]

This is the code of that feature:

```
<div class="row container-fluid mr-auto ml-auto" v-for="room in extraRooms">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <ValidationProvider
                    name="Pax hab. adicional"
                    rules="required"
                    v-slot="{ passed, failed, errors }"
                  >
                    <base-input
                      :label="'Pax hab. * ' + room "
                      :error="errors[0]"
                      :class="[{ 'has-success': passed }, { 'has-danger': failed }]"
                    >
                      <el-select
                        :class="!!errors[0] ? 'select-danger' : 'select-primary'"
                        placeholder="Seleccionar"
                        filterable
                        collapse-tags
                        v-model="paxExtraRoom[room]"
                      >
                        <el-option
                          v-for="item in selects.paxListMin"
                          v-if="item <= paxAllowed[room]"
                          :label="item"
                          :value="item">
                        </el-option>
                      </el-select>
                    </base-input>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <ValidationProvider
                    name="Adulto(s)"
                    rules="required|min:1|numeric|max_value:5|min_value:1"
                    v-slot="{ passed, failed, errors }"
                  >
                    <base-input
                      required
                      v-model="extraRoomsAges[room].adults"
                      label="Adultos"
                      placeholder="+18 años"
                      addon-left-icon="tim-icons icon-single-02"
                      type="text"
                      :error="errors[0]"
                      :class="[{ 'has-success': passed }, { 'has-danger': failed }]">
                    </base-input>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <ValidationProvider
                    name="Teenagers"
                    rules="required|min:1|numeric|max_value:4"
                    v-slot="{ passed, failed, errors }"
                  >
                    <base-input
                      required
                      v-model="extraRoomsAges[room].teenagers"
                      label="Adolescentes"
                      placeholder="+12 a -18"
                      addon-left-icon="tim-icons icon-single-02"
                      type="text"
                      :error="errors[0]"
                      :class="[{ 'has-success': passed }, { 'has-danger': failed }]">
                    </base-input>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <ValidationProvider
                    name="Niñ@s"
                    rules="required|min:1|numeric|max_value:4"
                    v-slot="{ passed, failed, errors }"
                  >
                    <base-input
                      required
                      v-model="extraRoomsAges[room].children"
                      label="Niñ@s"
                      placeholder="+3 a -11"
                      addon-left-icon="tim-icons icon-single-02"
                      type="text"
                      :error="errors[0]"
                      :class="[{ 'has-success': passed }, { 'has-danger': failed }]">
                    </base-input>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <ValidationProvider
                    name="Infantes"
                    rules="required|min:1|numeric|max_value:4"
                    v-slot="{ passed, failed, errors }"
                  >
                    <base-input
                      required
                      v-model="extraRoomsAges[room].infants"
                      label="Infantes"
                      placeholder="-3 años"
                      addon-left-icon="tim-icons icon-single-02"
                      type="text"
                      :error="errors[0]"
                      :class="[{ 'has-success': passed }, { 'has-danger': failed }]">
                    </base-input>
                  </ValidationProvider>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

So in order to bind the v-model to each input, i create them in a dynamic mode by watching the multiselect for changes like this:

```
watch: {
    extraRooms(value){
      // this.extraRoomsAges = []
      value.forEach(val => {
        if (this.extraRoomsAges[val] === undefined){
          this.extraRoomsAges[val] = {
            room: val,
            adults: 1,
            teenagers: 0,
            children: 0,
            infants: 0
          }
        }
      })
    },
}
```

So what i need is to detect changes on the four small inputs in order to calculate the total of the numbers in those inputs to get the total pax in the left larger input, so i tried with another watcher like this:

```
extraRoomsAges: {
      handler(value){
        console.log(value)
        value.forEach(val => {
          this.paxExtraRoom[val.room] = parseInt(val.adults) + parseInt(val.teenagers) + parseInt(val.children) + parseInt(val.infants)
        })
      },
      deep: true
    }
```

But nothing happens, it won't detect any changes, any idea of how can i achieve this?

Comment: changes `this.extraRoomsAges[val] = {...}` to `this.$set(this.extraRoomsAges, val, {...}`

Comment: Thanks Sphinx, like this?:

this.$set(this.extraRoomsAges[val] = {
            room: val,
            adults: 1,
            teenagers: 0,
            children: 0,
            infants: 0
          })

Comment: `this.$set(this.extraRoomsAges, val, { room: val, adults: 1, teenagers: 0, children: 0, infants: 0 })`; check [Vue API Guide for more detail](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)

Comment: Wow! thanks!, i didn't get the Syntax, now it's working!, can you please post it as an answer to mark it as the right one, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vue Guide: Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad),

Vue **does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties** to **an already created instance**. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, propertyName, value)` method. or [vm.$set(object, propertyName, value)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set)

So in your codes, **the fix** will be:

changes `this.extraRoomsAges[val] = {...}` to `this.$set(this.extraRoomsAges, val, { room: val, adults: 1, teenagers: 0, children: 0, infants: 0 })`